# Retrieve Data from local storage and display in tabulator

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage, tabulator

I had created a javascript function to store my data inside my local storage. The code is show below

```
 function SaveToLocalTakenReturn(no) {
    var MemberName = $("#txtMember" + no).val();
    var StaffName = $("#txtStaff" + no).val();
    var ChildFormType = $("#ddlChildFormType" + no).val();
    var Amount = $("#txtAmount" + no).val();
    var storedItems = [];
    var item = [{ MemberName }, { StaffName }, { ChildFormType }, { Amount }];
    if (localStorage['LocalTakenReturn'])
        storedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage['LocalTakenReturn']);
    storedItems.push(item);
    localStorage['LocalTakenReturn'] = JSON.stringify(storedItems);
}
```

And this success store the data inside the local storage and this the result of my local storage:

```
[[{"MemberName":"cktest5"},{"StaffName":"default"},{"ChildFormType":"RETURN"},{"Amount":"60"}],[{"MemberName":"cktest5"},{"StaffName":"default"},{"ChildFormType":"RETURN"},{"Amount":"50"}]]
```

And i have another page used to retrieve the local storage item. I used this javascript to retrieve. And this is the JS i used:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 if (localStorage['LocalTakenReturn'])
    {
        var printIcon = function (cell, formatterParams) { //plain text value
            return "<i class='fa fa-print'></i>";
        };

        data = JSON.parse(localStorage['LocalTakenReturn']);
        $("#the-table").tabulator({
            data: data,
            columns: [
              { title: "MemberNam2e", field: "", width: "20%", editor: false },
              { title: "StaffName", field: "StaffName", width: "20%", editor: false },
              { title: "ChildFormType", field: "ChildFormType", width: "20%", editor: false },
              { title: "Amount", field: "Amount", width: "20%", editor: false },
              { formatter: printIcon, width: "20%", align: "center", cellClick: function (e, cell) { SendToStorage(JSON.stringify(cell.getRow().getData()), cell.getRow(), cell.getRow().getData().memberName) } },
            ],
            cellEdited: function (id, data, row) {
                data = $("#the-table").tabulator("getData", true);
                localStorage['LocalTakenReturn'] = JSON.stringify(data);
            },
        });
    }
 });
```

It return me 3 row of records and all the field is null. The example of the result is like below :

```
MemberName | StaffName | ChildformType | Amount
[null]       [null]      [null]          [null]
[null]       [null]      [null]          [null]
```

Assume i have 2 records inside the local storage.

Why the data inside is null instead of the json data inside my local storage. Please help with whats wrong in the code?

Comment: problem solved. the problem occur at the javascript which used to insert to local storage. Change     var item = [{ MemberName }, { StaffName }, { ChildFormType }, { Amount }]; to var item = { "MemberName" : MemberName , "StaffName" : StaffName , "ChildFormType":ChildFormType ,  "Amount" : Amount };